# CentOS can't ping port 8080 on a Mac server

Tags: linux, centos, macos

I can't ping a Mac server at port 8080 from a CentOS machine, but I can ping that Mac server from any other machine, so the port is definitely open. Where should I start looking for the issue? Totally stuck.

```
[~/www@centos]# curl IP_ADDRESS_OF_MAC_SERVER:8080
```

That just hangs. Any other `curl` attempt, like for Google, works just fine.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

`traceroute` gave me this:

```
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `IP_ADDRESS_OF_MAC_SERVER:8080' on position 1 (argc 1)
```

`ping` gave me an unknown host, and `telnet`'s not installed.

Comment: curl isn't ping. You should start by testing basic network connectivity by actually using ping (ICMP), as well as traceroute. From there you should be able to see if there is something blocking traffic between the CentOS machine and the MAC server. If those tests work, then it's likely there is a firewall that is blocking specifically port 8080 between those two servers.

Comment: What do you get with 

    # telnet IP_ADDRESS 8080

Comment: See updated answer!

Comment: What does it mean to "ping a Mac server at port 8080"? And why are you trying to traceroute to an IP and port? Honestly, it sounds like you are messing with tools you have no idea how to use.

Comment: AFAIK, `traceroute` doesn't support port numbers. Use `tracepath` instead. Note that `tracepath` use the idiosyncratic syntax of `address/port` instead of `address:port`'